# Probability of random variable being lesser than the other

Tags: random-variable, independence, bounds

Say there are two *independent* random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and we have samples $\{x_1,\dots x_n\},\{y_1,\dots y_n\}$. I am interested in bounding the probability of the event $C = \mathbb{1}_{X<Y}$, namely bounding  $\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{E}(C) $.

I know that I can define $c_i=\mathbb{1}_{x_i<y_i}$,  and use Chernoff bound in the standard fashion to estimate 
$$\mathbb{P}\bigg(\hat C\in(\mathbb{E}(C)-\epsilon,\mathbb{E}(C)+\epsilon)\bigg) \geq 1-\delta $$

However, doing so means completely ignoring the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, hence seems wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

This is what I have done so far, based a partial answer by @passerby51's:

First, we define the U-statistic:
$$
U := \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 1\{X_j < Y_i\}
$$
Now, we would really like to follow Example 2.10 [from here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf), with $g(X_i,Y_j)=1_{X_i<Y_j}$. Unfortunately, $1_{X_i<Y_j}$ is not symmetric (as needed from the proof of the cited example). One lead as hinted by @passerby51, is to decompose $U$ into two terms, i.e.
$$
U := \frac1{n^2}\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^n 1\{X_k < Y_k\}}_{U_1}+\frac1{n^2}\underbrace{ \sum_{i<j} 1\{X_i < Y_j\}+1\{X_j < Y_i\}}_{U_2}
$$

Obviously, each term in $U_2$ is symmetric in $i,j$. I'm not sure what to do with $U_1$, so I'll ignore it for now. Redefine:
$$
U' := \frac1{n^2-n} \sum_{i<j} \big[1\{X_j < Y_i\}+1\{X_i < Y_j\}\big]=\frac1{n^2-n} \sum_{i<j} g(i,j)
$$

and again $\mathbb{E}(U')=\mathbb{E}(C)$. Next, if look at $U'$ as a function of $(X_1,\dots, X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$  it holds that:
$$|f(x_1,\dots,x_k,\dots,y_1,\dots,y_n)-f(x_1,\dots,x'_k,\dots,y_1,\dots,y_n)|\leq \frac{2\cdot(n-1)}{n\cdot(n-1)}=\frac 2 n$$

So using bounded differences inequality (see [Corollary 2.2 here](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf) ) we finally get
$$\mathbb{P}(|U'-\mathbb E(U')| \geq \epsilon) \leq 2\cdot e^{\frac{-n \epsilon^2} 2} $$

Make sense? how can I incorporate the diagonal indicators?

Comment: From what information are you attempting to estimate a sample size?  If you don't have any data, then what will you use?

Comment: I'm doing theoretical analysis, PAC style.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't answer my question: if you have no data and no information, then you have no basis at all to do any kind of analysis.  Could you please explain what information you will use or assume to estimate sample sizes?  If not, this question likely will be unanswerable.

Comment: @whuber I can sample $n_X$ samples from $D_X$ and $n_Y$ samples from $D_Y$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Partly.  But what would that mean in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?  Are you saying you can sample from the *joint* distribution of $(X,Y)$?  If that's the case, then the independence assumption would appear to have nothing to do with the solution, implying there really isn't any problem to solve.  That's why I am trying to get some clarification about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @whuber  If $X,Y$ are not independent, I _must_ sample the joint distribution $D_{XY}$, and treat any pair $(x_i,y_i)$ as a individual observation. On the other hand, if I have $\{x_1,\dot,x_n\}, \{y_1,\dot,y_n\}$,  it seem we have a bit more freedom. What I explain is that in the worst case, we can construct a new dataset $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^{n} $, as if the probability distribution was not the product distribution. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I believe that additional "freedom" may be illusory, because you do not have $n^2$ independent observations of the joint distribution.  A correct calculation of the variance of your estimate of the probability has to account for the *very high* correlation among all $n^2$ ordered pairs.  However, I still see no indication in your question that you have any concern about sample size, so perhaps you might like to modify the question so it better reflects what you want to know.

Answer (score 5):

Let $ F(y) := \mathbb P(X < y)$. We have $\mathbb P(X < Y | Y = y) = \mathbb P(X < y) =  F(y)$ by independence. Hence $p^* := \mathbb P (X < Y) = \mathbb E  F (Y)$.

Now, a good general estimate for $p^* = \mathbb E  F (Y)$ is the empirical mean $\hat p = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n  F(Y_i)$, and a good general estimate for $F$ is again the empirical mean, $\hat {F}(y) = \frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n  1(X_j < y)$.

Thus, in the absence of any information besides independence of $X$ and $Y$, the following is I believe the best estimate you can hope for
$$
\hat p = \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n 1\{X_j < Y_i\}.
$$
With obvious modifications, this works for uneven number of samples from $X$ and $Y$.

EDIT: You can use Hoeffding bound for U-statistics for this. (The terms of the sum are not independent as I originally mistakenly wrote. The variance of this estimate however is a lot smaller than what you had in your question: $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i < Y_i\}$. (Perhaps by a factor of $n^{-2}$, but not sure.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. when you say $U$-statistics you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Common_language_effect_size), right?
Also, since the terms in the sum are dependent, the conditions in Hoeffding inequality are not met, are they? can you formulate the expression you suggest bounding using Hoeffding ?

Comment: U-statistics are more general than Mann-Whitney (a special case). Also, Hoeffding proved its inequality for these guys originally. See for example example 2.10 here:http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf

Comment: If you feel more adventurous, concentratin inequalities for U-statistics, esp. the unbounded case is an active area of research: https://www.google.com/search?q=brenstein+inequlaity+for+U-statistics&oq=brenstein+inequlaity+for+U-statistics&aqs=chrome..69i57.5023j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=concentration+inequalities+for+U-statistics

Comment: Thanks again for the interesting answer. I have one more concern though - in Example 2.10 the function $g$ is symmetric, whereas here $g$ is the indicator function and certainly not symmetric. Is there a case covering that also?

Comment: @omerbp, you should be able to symmetrize it. Take out the diagonal elements and write the rest as $\sum_{i < j} 1\{X_j < Y_i\} + 1\{X_i < X_j\}$ which has a symmetric kernel. You can deal with diagonal sum separately.

Comment: You mean $X_i<Y_j$ in the second term, correct? Also, I not sure how to treat the diagonal. Can you please elaborate a bit further in you answer? Thanks!

Comment: I update the question according to your hint...

Comment: @omerbp, thanks for the correction. Thinking a bit more about it, this is not a usual U-statistics since X_i and Y_j sequences are not iid overall. Rather a two-sample one: See Chap 12 (Section 12.2) of https://www.amazon.com/Asymptotic-Statistics-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521784506.

Comment: @omerbp, I will think more about it. You should still be able to obtain concentration inequalities using these techniques. The issue is that I am not sure you gain much in the order of variance. The statistics is going to be still $\sqrt{n}$-consistent, but you would get a smaller asymptotic variance. I mean the difference will be in constants.

Comment: @omerbp, Re diagonal term in that expansion, it will be negligible relative to the pairwise term: $\frac1n \sum_k 1\{X_k < Y_k\}$ will concentrate around its mean so that $\frac1{n^2} \sum_k 1\{X_k < Y_k\}$ will be $O_P(\frac1n)$.